# Pass data between nodes in Visitor Pattern

Tags: c#, visitor-pattern

I have a Visitor Pattern in C#, where I want to be able to pass data between nodes. For example, `Visit(FunctionDeclStatement functionDeclStatement)` calls `functionDeclStatement.Body.Accept(this)`, and needs to be able to pass data to the visit functio n for`functionDeclStatement.Body`. What is a good way to do this? I suppose I could add parameters to the Visit functions, but that would be quite a mess.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the visitor pattern is the way to go:

#### The visitor pattern is used when:

1. Similar operations have to be performed on objects of different types grouped in a structure (a collection or a more complex structure).
2. There are many distinct and unrelated operations needed to be performed.

You are violating the second reason by creating a dependency between the items

Comment: Any idea what I could do instead, for walking an AST?

Comment: Possibly create it as a composit and call each node from the previous one.

Comment: Hm, I need to walk an abstract syntax tree though. The visitor pattern is usually the way to go for walking ASTs.

Comment: You can walk it and return some value from the visit function and then correlate them outside, like the expression trees visitor that creates the sql in entity framework.